# call textview and imageview in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, textview

hello I have made a layout of TextView(in it i've set a background image) and a simple TextView view and inflate both in adapter and showed them in a recycler  view, i can change the TextView(with background) and TextView as my wish in different list of recyclerview  but i also want to change the background of textview with its change in text.

this is arraylist where i entered two textview but i dont know where to enter background images

```java
wordList.add(new Word("1", "What is neuron?"));
wordList.add(new Word("2", "What is brain?"));
wordList.add(new Word("3", "What is gala?"));
wordList.add(new Word("4", "What is accurd?"));
```

```xml
<TextView android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:background="@drawable/teal"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="C"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/prod_name"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Comment: Your background images is stored on server or you saved in project only.

Comment: @YogeshNikamPatil  it is in my prroject

Comment: can you please show code where you set text to textview.

Comment: Or show screenshot what you want to do.

Comment: @YogeshNikamPatil All right; now i made three view; imageview(for background image); textview(foreground text); and textview for details. and problem is solved.

actually; what i wanted before was [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F_5svZZOU-kTgASlfrQun9M_7juu_KV6) and now it also looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F_5svZZOU-kTgASlfrQun9M_7juu_KV6)

Comment: thank you for your concern @YogeshNikamPatil . please help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/103157340?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting background images locally from drawable resources, then you will have to modify your **Word** class like this

```
Class Word { 
       private String tv1;
       private String tv2;
       private Drawable backgroundImage;

           Word(String a, String b, Drawable c){
              tv1=a; 
              tv2=b;
              backgroundImage=c
           }
       }
```

now you can add images like this

```
wordList.add(new Word("1", "What is neuron?", 
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_img)));
wordList.add(new Word("2", "What is brain?", 
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_img)));
wordList.add(new Word("3", "What is 
gala?", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_img)));
wordList.add(new Word("4", "What is 
accurd?", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_img)));
```

Now you have the background images in your ArrayList. You can use them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

at first I want to call background image of text view in recyclerView and change the background image accoring to my wish in different columns of recyclerview.

but now what i do is; i make textview and imageView as background of textview and call them easily in recyclerview and now i can change them according to my wish in different columns? do you get?